# Facebook Request Form's Skip button doesn't work

Tags: facebook, fbml

The fbml below generates an invite form using a multi-friend-selector. Everything works, except the Skip button. No matter what url I place in the action attribute, the action in the rendered form is *always* blank. This of course causes the Skip button to 404.

```
<div class="invite"> 
    <fb:serverFbml width="626">
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:request-form
                action="default.asp"
                target="_top"
                method="POST" 
                invite="true" 
                type="My Application" 
                content="<fb:req-choice url='facebook.com/somepage' label='Authorize my Application'/>">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="true" email_invite="false" cols="4" rows="1" actiontext="Invite your friends to use My Application!">
                </fb:multi-friend-selector>
            </fb:request-form>
        </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
</div>
```

**Edit:** On closer inspection, it looks like the 404 it goes to is http://www.facebook.com/plugins/serverfbml.php?. Found this as the only 404 response when tracking in Fiddler.

Comment: Have you tried absolute url (http://...)?

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. Still renders as an empty action :(.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to facebook on this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Official response from Facebook on [my bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12525); they've closed it. Only took five months :).

> Thanks for the report.
>
> As we are in the process of
>   deprecating FBML/FBJS, we will not be
>   adding additional features or fixing
>   current bugs. If you are creating an
>   application on facebook.com, please
>   implement your application using our
>   supported APIs, SDKs and Social
>   Plugins. Using these you can embed
>   many of the same social features
>   available in FBML.
>
> Please see more at our roadmap:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Comment: This reported bug is still open. Facebook is so terrible!

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem and it was driving me crazy but i managed to fix it. 
Try this :  `<fb:req-choice url='facebook.com/somepage' '`
just add another ' right after that, make sure you use space between them. It's funny how I spent 2 hours trying to figure that out. If you wish I'll just copy and paste the whole code. Hope this helps, I'm pretty sure it will since I had the exact same issue. Cheers.

Comment: If it will help others with this problem, go for it. I haven't done any Facebook development in the past few months, though the bug I reported is still in progress on their tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!!!

The fix was the following in my case:

action="http://YOURDOMAINNAME/APP/welcome.htm?${query_string}"

YOURDOMAINNAME must be the same as in your Canvas URL!

Comment: I am using a full URL linking to the domain of the canvas app, but I still get the 404 error sometimes when some script tries to load http://www.facebook.com/plugins/serverfbml.php.